# How can I make a DIV resize in a cell when the table is resized?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an hourly timeline type view that is a table, then I have activities the stretch along the timeline for as long as the activities are.
[image: timeline view]

It works fine until I hit certain browser sizes, namely iPad in witch the divs will start to spill over into other hours. They should stop at the red line since the event is only til 12pm.

Question is, how can I make the divs resize to stay within their boundaries?

I am using Bootstrap 3.2 and [Metronic](http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469) template

Thanks!

Here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12" id="EventsDiv">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:800px">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:200px">Event</th>
        <th style="width:60px">6A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">7A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">8A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">9A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">10A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">11A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">12P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">1P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">2P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">3P</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brad Storch
        <br />9:00 AM - 12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="ea-600AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-700AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-800AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-900AM">
          <div style="position:absolute; width:240px">
            <div style="width:240px; height:15px; position:absolute; top:0px;">
            Game Van</div>
          </div>
          <div style="position:absolute; width:180px">
            <div style="width:180px; height:15px; position:absolute; top:17px;">
            Hamster Ball</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="ea-1000AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-1100AM">
          <div style="position:absolute; width:120px">
            <div style="width:120px; height:15px; position:absolute; top:34px">
            Candy Cannon</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="ea-1200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-100PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-300PM"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use so many inline styles.  Your `width: 240px` is causing this issue, at least in part.  It's hard to diagnose fully with inline styles like this, you should move them to a CSS file.

Comment: The widths of the divs have to be different since they span times. I will be putting in external sheet, I am still developing.

Comment: Use percentages instead of fixed pixel widths.

Comment: i beleive you need to set the width using javascript calculating widths of tds

Comment: @DevlshOne when using percentages absolute positioned elements get their widths based on the width of the viewport in stead of the table

Answer (score 0):

I should try to use `colspan` and `rowspan`; set the `rowspan` of the event name equal to the number of items and set the colspan of the items equal to the number of hours:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<table border="1" width="100%">
       <tbody><tr>
        <th style="width:200px">Event</th>
        <th style="width:60px">6A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">7A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">8A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">9A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">10A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">11A</th>
        <th style="width:60px">12P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">1P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">2P</th>
        <th style="width:60px">3P</th>
      </tr>
 <tr> 
          <td rowspan="3">Brad Storch
        <br>9:00 AM - 12:00 PM
   </td>
        <td id="ea-600AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-700AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-800AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-900AM" colspan="4" style="background-color:red;">
         first
        </td>
        <td id="ea-100PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-300PM"></td>
</tr>
 <tr> 

        <td id="ea-600AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-700AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-800AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-900AM" colspan="3" style="background-color:yellow;">
                               Hamster Ball
        </td>
        <td id="ea-1200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-100PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-300PM"></td>
      </tr>
 <tr> 
        <td id="ea-600AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-700AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-800AM"></td>
   <td id="ea-900AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-1000AM"></td>
        <td id="ea-1100AM" colspan="2" style="background-color:green;">

            Candy Cannon
        </td>
        <td id="ea-100PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-200PM"></td>
        <td id="ea-300PM"></td>
      </tr> 
</tbody></table>  
</div>
</div>
```

demo: http://www.bootply.com/lkpipTYtVt

Also notice that Bootstrap provide you 'responsive' table, which got scrollbars for small screen widths: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Of course you can also use jQuery:

```
var cellWidth = $('#ea-600AM').innerWidth();
$('.hour4 div').css('width',cellWidth*4 + 3 + 'px').css('background-color','red');
$('.hour3 div').css('width',cellWidth*3 + 2 + 'px').css('background-color','green');
$('.hour2 div').css('width',cellWidth*2 + 1 + 'px').css('background-color','blue');
```

demo: http://www.bootply.com/SC93FAaHBG